Why is rax 0xffffffff00000001 instead of 0x0000000000000001 after setting eax to 1 in GDB?
I’m debugging an GAS assembly program using GDB on a x86-64 system. When I set the rax register to -1 and then set eax to 1, the value of rax becomes 0xffffffff00000001, but I expected it to be 0x0000000000000001, since I thought setting eax would clear the upper 32 bits of rax (based on what I’ve read about how x86-64 handles eax).
Here’s what I did:
(gdb) set $rax=-1
(gdb) info register rax
rax            0xffffffffffffffff  -1
(gdb) set $eax=1
(gdb) info register rax
rax            0xffffffff00000001  -4294967295        #  (???)


Yes, the CPU clears the top bits if you use 32 bit operations but gdb does not seem to. The debugger is not required to produce the same side effects as some cpu instruction. For example on architectures where loading a register also affects flags, using gdb will probably not do that either.

GDB changes registers by changing bytes in memory (e.g. in the target process's struct pt_regs on Linux via a ptrace system call). Not by running an instruction like mov eax, ... on the CPU in the context of the target process.
If I hadn't seen your experiment, I would have probably guessed that set $eax=1 might zero-extend to the full RAX to match asm semantics, but after thinking about it, it seems pretty reasonable that it doesn't.  This simplifies GDB's internals, not having to treat 8-bit and 16-bit partial registers differently from 32-bit partial registers, just modifying the width of the operand actually specified for all 4 widths.
If you want to set the full register, it's still easy to do that by naming it ($rax).  To truncate and zero-extend an arbitrary expression, I guess set $rax=(uint32_t)(a*b + c | d) or whatever.
For 128-bit $xmm0, leaving upper bits of $ymm0 / $zmm0 unmodified matches legacy-SSE semantics rather than VEX/EVEX semantics.  So it's something you might want even if simulating an asm instruction writing a register, and would be hard to get if zero-extending was the only option.
